# Why doesn't Wolverine's healing factor work any more?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

On the first issue of the Death of Wolverine, we see Reed Richards telling Wolverine that his healing factor doesn't work any more.

[image]

I don't know if any other comics lead up to these issues (I haven't read any), but is it explained why Wolverine lost his ability to heal himself?

Comment: Perhaps you need to read the preceding stories...?

Comment: @Moo which were...?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that there is a virus trying to "take over the world". This virus is  eliminating those who have control over viruses so they are free to take over without threat. Since Wolverine's healing ability made them unable to control him, he posed a threat, and this virus "destroyed" Wolverine's healing ability (or his ability got destroyed while fighting this virus).

> The story has grown from both volume 5 (Marvel Now!) and volume 6 (All-New Marvel Now!) of the Wolverine main series. The start of the storyline (Wolverine Volume 5 #5) details how a virus from the miniverse caused Wolverine's mutant healing factor to burn out and stop working.

Source: [Death of Wolverine - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Wolverine)

Comment: BTW, more at http://marvel.wikia.com/Wolverine_Vol_5_7

Comment: Is the answer based on Vol 5 7?

Comment: I just edited the answer to point to the comic series #.

Comment: An alien, intelligent pathogen from another dimension /universe that wants to take over the world but fears people with superhuman metabolisms? Does this mean everyone with metahuman healing is being attacked as well or is this Wolverine-specific?