# Can Deadpool be killed?

Tags: marvel, deadpool, thanos

Thanos cursed Deadpool to not die anymore. He already had his head decapitated, but after his head was put back in place, he returned to life.
Has anyone read anything about it? I mean, how to finish, definitely, the life of Deadpool.

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. His weakness is obviously that Thanos (or another ultra-powerful Eternal) decides to undo the curse, then hits him on the head with a piece of 2x4

Comment: Are you asking **IF** or **HOW**? Maybe sooner or later he'll lose his power, like his friend wolverine? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67427/why-doesnt-wolverines-healing-factor-work-any-more/67428#67428

Comment: Guys. Guys. We're all so preoccupied with whether or not we _could_ kill Deadpool, we didn't stop to think if we _should_.

Answer (score 20):

## No. If Thanos wills it, it cannot be undone.

It's true that Deadpool's regenerative power comes from Wolverine, and [Wolverine can be killed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine).

However, Thanos is an Eternal and even without the Infinity Gauntlet his [power is quite extensive](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos_(Earth-616)). Of most importance is Thanos's ability to travel through time and manipulate matter.

If Deadpool were close to death, Thanos could easily prevent this on an atomic scale, and if he were somehow to die, Thanos could travel through time and prevent the death from taking place. And even if this were impossible, his personal relationship with Death herself may mean she might not reap Deadpool.

Comment: Can you link sources? Quotes?

Comment: Ugh, death wants him to die so she can have him

Comment: Yes, the second argument is somewhat invalid, as she actually wants to reap him but can't

Comment: Even TOAA can't undo it?

Comment: A fundamental law in Greek mythology is that if one god/titan wills something, it cannot be undone by another. I wonder if the same thing applies in Marvel.

Answer (score 13):

Marvel have just announced "[The Death of Deadpool](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/marvel-announces-the-death-of-deadpool/)". If anyone can kill off Deadpool, it's Marvel.

> ***Marvel Comics has announced, via Nerdist, that they will be killing
> Deadpool in April's Deadpool #250, which will be the final issue of
> his ongoing series.***
>
> *“In all honesty, the story that you’re going to get in Deadpool #250,
> is a story that we really have been building to since the first issue
> of Deadpool NOW,” says Gerry Duggan, who has co-written the series
> with Brian Posehn since its most recent relaunch. “And it will
> absolutely feel – it will feel, I hope, readers will think that this
> is an appropriate end for this Deadpool.”*

Comment: Not dead dead, just comic-book dead. The idea that they'd kill off a major character just before their feature film airs is frankly ridiculous.

Comment: Psssh. A movie thats gonna bomb. Instead of appealing to its actual demographic they're trying to make a "family friendly" deadpool movie. Which is like trying to make a vegan friendly steak. It can be done but its not pretty

Comment: @HeathJamesCadriel: “Instead of appealing to its actual demographic they're trying to make a "family friendly" deadpool movie.” Are they indeed! Judging by the trailer, they may have failed.

Comment: @HeathJamesCadriel To be fair, comic deadpool was family friendly until 2007.

Comment: @HeathJamesCadriel with hindsight I think the statement it was going to bomb may have been a bit off :) - along with the family friendly bit

Answer (score 6):

#### Deadpool vol 1 issue #64 called "Funeral for a Freak", Frank Tieri's writing in which Thanos cursed Wade with immortality.

- The scope of Thanos' powers are rarely depicted, and almost never understood. If Thanos were to curse someone with eternal life, it is a threat I can see being enacted and unable to be broken except by a being whose powers rival Thanos'.

[image: A series of panels against an outer space background. Panel 1: Thanos, in silhouette, says "I am watching you, Deadpool..." while looking at a portal. Through the portal, Deadpool can be seen saying "...cuz the alternative stings." Panel 2: Thanos, in silhouette, says "...and I do not like your attitude." An image of Deadpool hangs over his head. Panel 3: A zoomed out view of a space station, with an image of Deadpool kissing a skull visible. Thanos continues "The woman I love seems to love you." Panel 4: Thanos, looking at a representation of Lady Death, says "You see, I have built a shrine to her. So I will not let you die and get between us." Panel 5: Thanos' hand clutches a wilting rose as he says "No, you will never know Death's loving embrace." Panel 6: Thanos, silhouetted, sits in a throne. He says "Hear me well, Deadpool...]

[image: Against a background of stars and planets, clutching a wilting rose in one hand, and clenching the arm rest of his stone throne with the other so hard it begins to crumble, Thanos says, eyes flaring and something exploding in the background: "...you will find that there is a fate worse than death... ...which is NOT being able to die! Consider yourself CURSED, my adversary. Cursed with LIFE!"]

Comment: On a separate note, how does a skeleton have breasts?

Comment: @marcellothearcane her hands are also not bone, so we can assume only the head is without flesh.

Answer (score 3):

Well recently theres a few series of comics that delt with this. The first was the Deadpool series that recently ended and now we have the new one. Where deadpool loses his healing factor for a time and he seems rather killable but you find out it was just vastly slowed down. Theres also Deadpool vs the Marvel universe series, where he has Daken and X-23 tied up with flamethrowers pointed at them that light them up everytime they start to regen, which is how at the time he says he'd deal with his own healing factor. Finally in Deadpool vs Deadpool its deadpools killing each other with weapons designed to kill other Deadpools, for example theres a energy gun that can kill a deadpool without him regenerating. Deadpool also exploits his teleporter to kill another by sending half his body somewhere else.
So yes deadpool can die or basically be considered dead, but he'd probably never be truly dead without having that curse removed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Q could easily kill Deadpool.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be possible, since his healing factor is similar to Wolverine's and [Wolverine can be killed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14347/how-to-kill-wolverine).

From Deadpool's article on [*marvel.com*](http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_%28Wade_Wilson%29), under *Powers*, we know that

> Deadpool possesses a superhuman healing factor derived from that of the mutant Wolverine that allows him to regenerate damaged or destroyed areas of his cellular structure at a rate far greater than that of an ordinary human. As such, he can regrow severed limbs or vital organs. The speed at which this healing factor works varies in direct proportion to the severity of the damage Deadpool suffers. This healing factor also affords Deadpool a virtual immunity to poisons and most drugs, as well as an enhanced resistance to diseases and an extended life span. Unlike Wolverine’s natural healing factor, Deadpool’s is mentally driven to a partial extent.

So, since his ability is similar to Wolverine's, I think we can assume that he *can* be killed, but it would be really really hard.

Answer (score 0):

In the Deadpool classics TPB, in the first or second book of it there is an issue where Deadpool looses the ability to regenerate for some reason that I cant remember, and he gets the scientist that experimented on him in to get him the powers in the first place to do more work on him, and he does fix the regenerative powers for the most part, but it is explained that if Deadpool gets a major major injury, such as looses a limb, then the limb stays off, it cant regrow or reattach itself.

Answer (score -1):

Deadpool is immortal. the only way to kill him would be through thanos removing the curse, then striking his healing factor with carbonadium OR complete atomization. Although, marvel revealed they will be killing him. This still may not be true, as knowing that he can break the fourth wall, they could make a joke ending where he lives.

Comment: not bad but i wonder where this came from ?

Answer (score -1):

He can die if gamma goes into him the gamma radiation will destroy his healing factor and his cancer will kill him

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Deadpool comics; has this happened before?

Comment: Deadpool #1, he traveled to Antarctica to sabotage a gamma reactor. Swimming inside it resulted in his healing factor losing its potency. He wound up solving it with some of Hulk's blood.

Answer (score -1):

Deadpool's immortality doesn't originate from his healing factor.  Thanos placed a curse on him, so that he would never die, because of the love triangle between Thanos, Deadpool, and Death.

Marvel said they would kill him off (they may have already - I don't read them anymore)

Anyway, imagine Deadpool having The Flash's abilities along with his own...
Better healing factor than Wolverine
Immortal due to Thanos
(Once mastered, he would be faster than the speed of light--like 100x faster than superman, be able to time travel, go into different dimensions, do infinite mass punches, run on water obv.  and so on.)
With his weapons and style of fighting, this would be a wicked upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

No. He's been cursed by Thanos and also has the regenerative powers enhanced

Answer (score -3):

Deadpool can't die even Ghost Rider's penance stare couldn't kill him. It turned Ghost Rider back to Johnny Blaze. Also, Thanos cursed him -- he survived complete incineration.

Comment: When and where did he survive incineration? I'm not saying he didn't, but it would help to add the references to the point :)

Comment: @mooz I think he's referring to agent of weapon x, prior to the udon Deadpool/agent x series. Deadpool was liquidfired but you know, he got better