# What happens if Deadpool can no longer access food?

Tags: comics, deadpool

Ok. Deadpool is quick witted, smart, a weapons expert, has mercenary fighting skills, lightning fast reflexes, and he can regenerate from any injury, even death.
He has no other known super powers.

If Deadpool was severely injured(or a little bit dead), was disarmed and encased in the center of a 12 foot cube of concrete, would he continue to be immortal, or would he starve?

Comment: Starving for eternity is a bad way to live.

Comment: No mo' chimichungas.

Comment: Yams infected with tree-of-life virus.

Comment: Purely thermodynamically I assume he would die.

Comment: Never assume thermodynamics holds sway in the Marvel Universe! :)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67820/1167

Comment: @MajorStackings He doesn't even like Chimichangas, he just likes to say the word :P

Comment: @Oak That's too funny. I thought this question up last night over a plate....of chimichangas.

Comment: “A little bit dead”.

Comment: Self-cannibalism. He would do it.

Comment: Movie or comics continuity?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Why not both? In the history of comics and movie versions of them (especially in Marvel), _Deadpool_ (movie) is the only one I was happy enough to say it is highly relevant in character development with its comic version.

Comment: @apollo: ^_^ Chiefly because, so far, there exists an answer for the comic book,s, but not for the movie.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Silly me, I didn't look at the answers :) You are right! But I guess you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the comics continuity, he [simply survives](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2016/02/28/comic-book-questions-answered-can-wolverine-or-deadpool-starve-to-death/2/), albeit in bad shape. After 800 years in a freezer with no apparent food, he's still alive. This may be in part due to Thanos cursing him with eternal life rather than it entirely being a matter of a mutant healing factor.

From *The Messiah War*:

[image: Deadpool entering freezer]
[image: Deadpool enduring the ages]
[image: Deadpool found]

Answer (score -2):

He would most likely just use the teleportation belt to obtain some Chimichangas. But ultimately, he would just sit there until his body heals and then get food.

Answer (score -2):

He'd just use his powers to find some food.  Not sure if the regeration powers he has would allow him to survive without food or not.